# How to use args parser

Tags: dart

I'm trying to use this package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/args

With this code:

```dart
  var parser = new ArgParser();

  parser.addFlag("test", abbr: 't');
  var test = parser.parse(["--test"]);
  print(test["test"]);
```

When I do `dart myapp.dart --test` I get true. Ok, but even without `--test` I get true... Can you explain to me how to use this package?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'even without `--test`'. You need to pass the `args` you get passed to `main()` to `parse()` to get the actual command line arguments parsed. Currently always `["--test"]` is parsed no matter which arguments you add on the command line.

```dart
import 'package:args/args.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  var parser = new ArgParser();

  parser.addFlag("test", abbr: 't');
  var test = parser.parse(args);
  print(test["test"]);
}
```

> dart -c main.dart

prints `false`